# How did Google's repositories get in my /var/lib/apt/lists?

Tags: apt, package-management, google

I installed google-earth-stable no problem. Now I noticed these files in my /var/lib/apt/lists directory:

```
$ ls /var/lib/apt/lists | grep google
dl.google.com_linux_earth_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
dl.google.com_linux_earth_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages
dl.google.com_linux_earth_deb_dists_stable_Release
dl.google.com_linux_earth_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg
```

I haven't edited sources.list and there's no mention of Google there. I didn't know Google Earth wasn't in the default repos. So I'm wondering why the installation worked in the first place and why those files are there.

edit: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` contains one file, `google-earth.list`:

```
$ cat google-earth.list 
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

How did that get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Google Earth or Google Chrome from the Google website also adds the repository.

> Google’s Linux software packages will automatically configure the repository settings necessary to keep your Google Linux applications up-to-date. Please download and install packages from the appropriate product pages.

Reference: https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/